# How do i add a game center leader board to my app

Tags: swift5

There are lots of tutorials for older versions online, but they arent in swift 5, I was wondering what code was needed. I already added game center to the settings thing in xcode and added a leader board to my app in app store connect, just wondering how to code it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for best results. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.